# Merging Overlapping Polygons without dissolving?

Tags: qgis

I have multiple seperate shapefiles with polygons that overlap one another. I want to merge them into one shapefile with a single attribute table so I can find sqkm for all of the polygons.

Every time I merge them it cuts all of the polygons into seperate polys; so for example there are 16 polygons to merge into one shapefile, and after merging I have 40 features.

Comment: Can you please show some graphical support of your problem?

Comment: It would also help if you named the tools and the settings within them exactly.

Comment: Agree, please advise on some data example. Have you tried to merge by attribute using Merge Vector layers and then GDAL Dissolve in QGIS?

Comment: dissolve and then multipart to singlepart should work. Add some screenshots or drawing showing what you want to achieve

Comment: Maybe `ogr2ogr -update -append one.shp two.shp -nln one`.